# CefSharp - Published: Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.Core.Runtime.dll'

Tags: c#, publish, cefsharp

Using CefSharp.WinForms (NuGet Download) Version: 99.2.140

I've updated .csproj file to include

```
<CefSharpAnyCpuSupport>true</CefSharpAnyCpuSupport>
```

And updated the App.config file to inlcude:

```
<runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <probing privatePath="x86"/>
      </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Using: Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2022 Redistributable (x86) - 14.31.31103
Using: Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2022 Redistributable (x64) - 14.31.31103
(I've set the build to be explicity x86 & x64 which had the same results.)

I've built a couple of Solutions using CefSharp and they both have the same issue.  They run perfectly from Visual Studios (Debug OR Release Mode).  But, once I publish it.  Bam..
"Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.Core.Runtime.dll'..."

Ughh, I'm stuck :(
Sincerely;
Alex.

PS.  Here's my current Code in class Program.  A 'Could not load file...
'CefSharp.Core.Runtime.. ' will occur when Build | Platform target: AnyCPU or x64.  It will work if Platform targe set to x86

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    public static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        CefRuntime.SubscribeAnyCpuAssemblyResolver();
        //For Windows 7 and above, best to include relevant app.manifest entries as well
        Cef.EnableHighDPISupport();
        var exitCode = CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.SelfHost.Main(args);

        if (exitCode >= 0)
        {
            return exitCode;
        }

        var settings = new CefSettings()
        {
            //By default CefSharp will use an in-memory cache, you need to specify a Cache Folder to persist data
            CachePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "CefSharp\\Cache"),
            BrowserSubprocessPath = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName
        };

        //Example of setting a command line argument
        //Enables WebRTC
        // - CEF Doesn't currently support permissions on a per browser basis see https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/2582/allow-run-time-handling-of-media-access
        // - CEF Doesn't currently support displaying a UI for media access permissions
        //
        //NOTE: WebRTC Device Id's aren't persisted as they are in Chrome see https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/2064/persist-webrtc-deviceids-across-restart
        settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("enable-media-stream");
        //https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#use-fake-ui-for-media-stream
        settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("use-fake-ui-for-media-stream");
        //For screen sharing add (see https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/2582/allow-run-time-handling-of-media-access#comment-58677180)
        settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("enable-usermedia-screen-capturing");

        //Perform dependency check to make sure all relevant resources are in our output directory.
        //IMPORTANT: MUST set performDependencyCheck false
        Cef.Initialize(settings, performDependencyCheck: false, browserProcessHandler: null);

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new MainForm());

        return 0;
    }
}
```

I get the following.NET Runtime error

> Application: InventoryDB.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319
> Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
> Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException at
> CefSharp.Cef.EnableHighDPISupport() at
> InventoryDB.Program.Main(System.String[])

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243700/discussion-on-question-by-alex-mcintosh-cefsharp-published-could-not-load-fil).

Comment: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues?q=is%3Aissue+cefsharp.core.runtime.dll