# CefSharp: Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.Core.Runtime.dll' or one of its dependencies

Tags: vb.net, winforms, publish, cefsharp

I have a vb.net winform with chromium browser which works fine testing in visual studio, but not when published to another PC.

I get the following error: Could not load file or assembly CefSharp.Core.Runtime.dll or one of its dependencies

In my Publish Application Files settings CefSharp.Core.Runtime.dll is set to Include.

These questions for C# haven’t helped me (In desperation I installed the Microsoft Visual C Redistributable):

[CefSharp - Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.Core.dll' or one of its dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42365731/cefsharp-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-cefsharp-core-dll-or-one-of-its-dep)

[Error: Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.Core.Runtime.dll' or one of its dependencies. Only on some pcs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70231536/error-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-cefsharp-core-runtime-dll-or-one-of-its)

[CefSharp - Published: Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.Core.Runtime.dll'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71741016/cefsharp-published-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-cefsharp-core-runtime-dll)

Any ideas how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/discussions/4056

Comment: Also make sure the required Visual C ++ Runtime is installed https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/103/NuGet/Readme.txt#L26